# What is correct asset type for buttons in Android?

Tags: android, svg, assets

I would like to have simple geometry buttons in my application, like play, stop, record buttons on videocamera.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to prepare good asset for them.

If choose `Image Asset` to place differen resolutions in differen folder, I am confused by `Asset Studio` available options:

[image]

Here is a strange list of icon types, but no one says "button" icons.

Also, I am not sure, what size to choose for mid-resolution in pixels.

Next, if I choose `Vector Asset` I face with limited support of `SVG` in this program. At least, it doesn't understand SVGs created with Adobe Illustrator.

So, what is the best choice?

**UPDATE**

I drew blue shape in Adobe Illustrator and expoted it to SVG. The result is following:

[image]

I.e. color is lost and error message

```
In share.svg:
ERROR@ line 1 <defs> is not supported
```

displayed.

Comment: Mind that VectorDrawables are a **much limited subset** of SVG files.

Answer (score 1):

Those options are for creating launcher, notification and actiobar icons but for a button u need to have a image and convert it manually into various resolutions and place it in the respective folders or else online converters are available to do that job for u.

Comment: I can create any image. The question is how to know, which image sizes to create?

Comment: The entire detail is specified here...https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

As written here https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
that is, `drawable-mdpi`

About SVG:

You can easily implement data of SVG file using `vector` drawable. 
you just can use `drawable` folder for vector graphic. Just put here some any `vector` file and use it as a background source.

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ for example, here you can craete your own image set.

Comment: If `Android Studio` tool doesn't understand some `SVG`, doesn't this mean I also can't use it in application too?

Comment: Ok. have you tried to create vector manually inside drawable folder and paste raw svg data?